# File path as argument from Futter to android Native using method channel

Tags: android, flutter, cross-platform

I need to pass images from Flutter after images have been successfully captured to android native to process them. So I tried by passing their path as a string using method channel and using them in android native. but the android native is unable to read the file from the paths.
My path in Flutter is like this

```
/data/user/0/com.example.sunscape/cache/2021-02-08 17:51:34.860806.png
```

now after passing it to android I tried this code to access the image located at the above path

```
 File imgFile1 = new File(img_path);
```

but my app is crashing with the error

```
 Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException:  /data/user/0/com.example.sunscape/cache/2021-02-08 17:51:37.768294.png (No such file or directory)
```

can anyone suggest a better way to pass images through the method channel?

Comment: Did you try imgFile1.exists() before? And are : characters allowed in file names?

Comment: Dont let your app crash by catching that exception.